# how to assign the correct colormap to countourf in python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, color-mapping

I am trying to understand how countourf works, so I created the following simple function:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap

def example(vectorofpoints):

answerarray = []
for p in vectorofpoints:
    if p[0]<0.9:
        if p[1]<0.9:
            answerarray.append(0)
        else:
            answerarray.append(1)
    else:
        if p[1]<0.9:
            answerarray.append(2)
        if p[1]>=0.9:
            answerarray.append(3)
return np.array(answerarray)
```

Now I would like to plot the values in the region [0.8,1.10]x[0.8,1.10], so I did the following:

```
colors = ('red', 'blue', 'lightgreen', 'gray', 'cyan')

cmap = ListedColormap(colors[:4])
```

Now I want that the regions where example = 0 are colored in red, the regions where  it is equal to 1 in blue and so on. Note that I defined more colors than needed.

I did this:

```
xx1, xx2 = np.meshgrid(np.arange(0.8,1.10, 0.01),np.arange(0.8,1.10, 0.01))

Z = predict2(meanvectorlist,covmatrixlist,np.array([xx1.ravel(), xx2.ravel()]).T)

Z = Z.reshape(xx1.shape)

plt.contourf(xx1, xx2, Z,cmap=cmap, alpha=0.4,linewidths=2)
```

I expected a region divided in squares:

1. x < 0.9, y< 0.9   red square
2. x < 0.9, y >0.9  blue square
3. x >=0.9, y <0.9 lightgreen square
4. x>= 0.9, y >=0.9 gray square

Instead I get the following image
[image]

1. Why is the gray square actually cyan?
2. Why is a small vertical region lightgreen coloured appearing?
3. Why is a gray line at the boundaries of the cyan region appearing?

Comment: 1. cyan must be in your colormap, probably you made a mistake somewhere forgetting `[:4]` when creating the colormap or similar. This is consistent with 3., namely that there are 4 regions, but your colormap has five colors, so a contour is shown with that color as well. Concerning 2. consider that in a landscape you cannot walk from 50m height to 150m height without passing 100m height.

Comment: `contourf` interpolates the data so you won't get a sharp edge between your colors and probably that's why you get the cyan you don't want. Instead try using `pcolor`. It shows piecewise constant colors.